# import videos from google+ album -to- youtube channel

Tags: youtube, synchronization, google-plus

from youtube to google+ is easy. But on the other way...

I have a google plus profile and a youtube channel linked to it. But -from youtube- I can't see the videos that are inside my google+ album.

These video are shared in public. So they should appear in the youtube chanel linked with that google account profile, right?

I have many google+ albums that contains photos + videos. I need to keep that order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FYI, there is now a "Import your videos from Google+" option under the uploads section.

Answer (score 1):

Google+ content is not currently available on YouTube. If you wish to have Google+ videos hosted on a YouTube channel, you will have to manually download the videos and upload them.